# Properly handling unicode characters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, ruby-1.9

By default Rails allows users of our application to input non-utf8 data, such as: `¶®«¼`

However when we attempt to retrieve the data from our database and render it in a template Rails incorrectly assumes that it is in UTF-8 format and throws an error.

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

What is the best way to handle this? I have seen one fix that suggested sanitizing the data in every place the user can input it. However, that would involve changing a considerable amount of code and it would strip out the characters entirely. Ideally we would want some characters converted to their UTF-8 equivalents.

Our environment:

```
Ruby: 1.9.1
Rails 2.3.5
MySql Gem: 2.8.1
```

This is a serious and urgent problem for us so your answers are very appreciated!

Comment: `nput non-utf8 data, such as xxx` - why those chars are not UTF8?

`sanitizing the data in every place ` is not related to encoding as I can see. It means make sure user does not inject invalid strings (like `<script>alert('haacked')</script>` tags etc).

Latstly, what do you see in the database and what type of column do you have?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but if it is that urgent, starting a bounty might be a good idea.

Comment: Dmitriy: I think the problem might be that the database encoding was switched to UTF8 from Latin1 without cleaning up the data. I've tried to switch it back to latin1 with no luck, Rails still treats it as UTF8.

Database encoding: utf8
Table encoding: utf8
Column type: Text

Switching database and table encodings did not solve the problem. Rails still thinks the string is UTF8 encoded.

egarcia: Thanks for the suggestion. I would have added a bounty but you have to wait two days before you can add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the mysql2 gem (version 0.1.6 or greater) instead of mysql.

It's still fairly new, but has been working well for me in production and will retrieve all strings from your DB as utf-8.

Just install the gem and change your database.yml file to contain "adapter: mysql2"